# Visual Basic label

Tags: vb.net

If i have information (for example a name) in a label on a form in Visual Basic, how do I save this information in a .txt file?

Thanks

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the classes in the [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace. Look at `File` and its methods.

This example uses one overload of [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText("Path To Text File.txt", myLabel.Text)
```

It will write the text value of the `myLabel` control to the specifies text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file system object for ealier versions of Visual basic.

' VBScript

```
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine(label.caption)
MyFile.Close
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(VS.85).aspx

or

```
Sub Create_File()
    Dim fso, txtfile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtfile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
    txtfile.Write (lable.caption) ' Write a line.
    ' Write a line with a newline character.
    txtfile.WriteLine("Testing 1, 2, 3.")
    ' Write three newline characters to the file.
    txtfile.WriteBlankLines(3)
    txtfile.Close
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263346(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You use StreamWriter to do that. Here's an example:

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
file.Close()
```

If you want to know how to **read** from txt files, here's a example code:

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
MsgBox(fileReader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it directly into the place you needed

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("filename.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("Your Text Here~")
file.Close()
```